# nullPointer when reading resources

Tags: java, resources

I am trying to read resources in java and I am getting `NullPointerException` again and again. The codes I have tried is

```
String fileName = "file/services.json";
ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

I get `NullPointerException` at third line.

```
String fileName = "file/services.json";
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

In this `is` is null. 
My project structure is `src/main/java/com/xyz/readResources.java` for source folder and `src/main/resources/file/services.json` for the resources.

Can someone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS. My company uses .xml file to specify paths and classpath. My current .xml file has these as folder listed in it.

```
<property name="allow.empty.sources.dir" value="true" />
<property name="sources.dir" value="${basedir}/src/main/java" />
<property name="tests.dir" value="${basedir}/src/test/java" />
<property name="tests.additional.runtime.classpath" value="${basedir}/src/test/resources" />
```

what's the property name for resources for main? I am not able to find that and maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: Add a slash in Front of "file" /file/services.json";

Comment: yes i did. It cannot find the resource file `services.json`

Comment: @Jens Trying with `filename="/file/services.json`

Comment: @PrateekGupta quite right, my apologies for flagging. This shouldn't be closed (even though it is duplicate. But duplicates aren't that bad, because they bring a new view)

Comment: Is the resources folder in the classpath?

Comment: @Jens not working with `filename="/file/services.json`.

Comment: Hey @Jens, How would `/file/...` work? `file` isn't in the root folder.

Comment: @ScaryWombat just services.json also not working

Comment: @progyammer it is inside of the classpath

Comment: @progyammer why should my `.java` file be in the resources folder? `.java` file should be in the source folder.

Comment: @PrateekGupta Right. Sorry! My bad :P

Comment: @progyammer java files are no resources. Learn about maven projects before posting such comments

Comment: @PrateekGupta can you take a Look into the target/classes folder if the file/service.json exists?